# Next.js Dynamic Link Social Media preview Opengraph

Tags: javascript, next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js13, meta-tags

I am working on a Next.js project (version 13, pages router (not app)) where I need to implement dynamic previews similar to YouTube or StackOverflow. Specifically, my goal is to generate different previews for links with query parameters (e.g., /awarded?token=abc123). The previews should change based on the token value.

I am using Server-Side Rendering (SSR) with getServerSideProps to fetch data based on the token and set the meta tags dynamically. However, I am facing an issue where the data fetched in getServerSideProps is not being logged to the console, and the dynamic meta tags are not reflecting the expected content.

**fetchPreviewBasedOnToken.ts**

```
import { awardReasonsDev, awardReasonsProd } from '@src/utils/awardReasons';
import { CONSTANTS } from '@src/utils/constants';
import { getAwardFromToken } from './getAwardFromToken';

export type AwardData = {
  title: string;
  description: string;
};

export async function fetchPreviewBasedOnToken(
  token: string,
): Promise<AwardData> {
  const awardReasons =
    process.env.environment === 'DEV' || process.env.environment === 'LOCAL'
      ? awardReasonsDev
      : awardReasonsProd;
  const awardToken = token;
  const awardIndexString = awardToken.slice(CONSTANTS.TOKEN_LENGTH);
  const awardIndex = parseInt(awardIndexString, 10);

  const currentAward = getAwardFromToken(awardToken, awardReasons, awardIndex);
  if (!currentAward) {
    throw new Error('Award not found');
  }

  return {
    title: currentAward?.title,
    description: currentAward?.body,
  };
}
```

**pages/awarded.tsx:**

```
import { GetServerSideProps } from 'next';
import Head from 'next/head';
import { fetchPreviewBasedOnToken } from '@src/function/fetchPreviewByToken';

type Props = {
  award: AwardData | null;
};

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const token = context.query.token as string;
  try {
    const data = await fetchPreviewBasedOnToken(token);
    console.log("Fetched Data: ", data);
    return { props: { award: data || null } };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error: ", error);
    return { props: { award: null } };
  }
};

  const currentPageUrl = `https://example.com/awarded/?token=${router.query.token}`;

return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>{award?.title}</title>
        <meta property="og:title" content={award?.title} />
        <meta property="og:description" content={award?.description} />
        <meta
          property="og:image"
          content="https://example.com/previewImage.jpeg"
        />
        <meta property="og:url" content={currentPageUrl} />
        <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
      </Head>
// rest of the component
    </div>
  );
```

**Issues I'm facing:**

1. The console.log in getServerSideProps does not output anything in my server logs.
2. The dynamic meta tags do not reflect the data fetched based on the token.
3. though the preview for index.tsx appears but this page's preview don't appears on social media (checked from different tools as well)

Could someone help me identify what I might be missing or doing wrong? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!